# xcode exc_bad_access: Please teach how to properly debug this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm still learning XCode with only the net as my teacher.

I have 4 tab item which worked previously. Now 1 of them is causing my app crash. I've tried to create breakpoint at the start of my failing tab's viewcontroller. But it's still throwing error message.

I search the web about the message's meaning and it may cause by deallocate objects. The message is:

```
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x.....)"
```

Please give me a clue how to find my problem's source...kind of lost here.

Here is screenshot:

[image: drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Eajdcb7PRGWW1PejQ0UmRqWjg/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Is TKurningEngine your code? I've never heard of it and can't find it via google. If so then so the positionglyphs code.

Comment: @rmaddy thank for the link...reading it now

Comment: @MartinH no. I don't know what is TKerningEngine is

Comment: Ok! Got the culprit now...@rmaddy: really appreciate your link. Now I learn how to expand the call stack! @MartinH:the problem lies on the font related. I try to use Trebuchet MS Italic on refresh control. And it breaks my app. Thanks for your clue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to debug these errors is with NSZombies, which will show you where/what error is occurring.  To do this go to the "product" menu, then select "edit scheme".  Go to "run yourApp.app", then go to "arguments".  Add NSZombieEnabled to "environment variables" and set value to YES.  Run your app again and the error should become clear.

Comment: Thank you for your introduction on NSZombies. I tried it just now, but the error code still the same. Where should I look on more error details? The debugger output still only write: (lldb)

Comment: Really appreciate about how to setup NSZombie. It really helps.

Comment: You can also more easily enable zombies by choosing "Scheme" - "Edit scheme" from the "Product" menu, go to "Diagnostics" tab, and clicking on "Enable Zombie Objects".